# Sencha workspace with multiple repositories

Tags: git, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I have a doubt with Sencha manages the workspaces, I have a workspace with two different applications, each application should be a different repository, is this possible? how to do it??  I am working with Webstorm IDE but I suppose don´t care..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and is git submodules.

Here it goes documentation about this type of implementations or workspaces.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule